# efficient moving, robust scale estimate for python array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a fast and efficient way to compute a robust, moving scale estimate for a set of data.  I'm working with 1d arrays of typically 3-400k elements.  Up until recently I've been working with simulated data (with no catastrophic outliers), and the move_std function from the excellent Bottleneck package has served me well.  However, as I've transitioned to noisy data, the std is no longer sufficiently well behaved as to be useful.

In the past I've used a very simple biweight mid-variance code element-by-element to deal with the problem of poorly behaved distributions:

```
def bwmv(data_array):
    cent = np.median(data_array)
    MAD = np.median(np.abs(data_array-cent))
    u = (data_array-cent) / 9. / MAD
    uu = u*u
    I = np.asarray((uu <= 1.), dtype=int)
    return np.sqrt(len(data_array) * np.sum((data_array-cent)**2 * (1.-uu)**4 * I)\
            /(np.sum((1.-uu) * (1.-5*uu) * I)**2))
```

however the arrays I'm working with now are large enough that this is prohibitively slow.  Does anyone know of a package that provides such an estimator, or have any recommendation of how to approach this in a fast and efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

I've used a simple low-pass filter in similar situations.

Conceptually, you can get a moving estimate for the mean with `fac = 0.99; filtered[k] = fac*filtered[k-1] + (1-fac)*data[k]`, which is extremely efficient to implement (in C). A slightly more fancy IIR filter than this one, the butterworth low-pass, is easy to setup in scipy:

```
b, a = scipy.signal.butter(2, 0.1)
filtered = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, data)
```

To get an estimate for the "scale", you can subtract this "mean estimate" from the data. This actually turns the low-pass into a high-pass filter. Take the abs() of that and run it through another low-pass filter.

The result might look like this:

[image: script output]

Full script:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.signal import lfilter, butter

data = randn(1000)
data[300:] += 1.0
data[600:] *= 3.0
b, a = butter(2, 0.03)
mean_estimate = lfilter(b, a, data)
scale_estimate = lfilter(b, a, abs(data-mean_estimate))

plot(data, '.')
plot(mean_estimate)
plot(mean_estimate + scale_estimate, color='k')
plot(mean_estimate - scale_estimate, color='k')

show()
```

Obviously, the butter() parameters need to be tuned to your problem. If you set the order to 1 instead of 2, you get exactly the simple filter that I described first.

Disclaimer: this is an engineer's take on the problem. This approach is probably not sound in any statistical or mathematical way. Also, I'm not sure if it really solves your problem (please explain better if it doesn't), but don't worry, I've had some fun doing this, either way ;-)